# Email Formatting Issues

Tags: vb.net, email, formatting, email-formats

I am trying to print an email sent through my code. While printing in A4 paper format this is printed as expected but when I chose paper size as Letter, my footer is pushed to next page and becomes the header of the page. Can anyone help and advise if this can be sorted with some settings?

Thanks in Advance.
Regards
Yogesh

Answer (score 0):

Reduce size of margin-bottom and marin-top. otherwise implement function if paper size changed reduce and increase font-size.

Comment: Thanks Deepak, but didn't helped :(